# Writing to stdout and stderr will mix together

Tags: logging, io, buffer, stdout

I am implementing a console logger, and I am using `setvbuf()` to let the `stdout` and `stderr` work in `_IONBF` mode, so that every time I use `fwrite()`, the content should be immediately flushed to the console, however, after I call `fwrite("hello world1", stdout)`, and then call `fwrite("hello world2", stderr)`, the output is quite weird because they were printed in an interleaved manner, like `"hello hello world2 world1"`.

I am only using a single thread, and I noticed that every time the logs got mixed, they were trucated at the space area, which make me really confused, where is the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? I guess, you are using python here?